# Why can’t we use energy momentum relation given as $E=pc^2/v$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, energy, momentum, dispersion

Why don’t we use energy momentum relation as $E=pc^2/v$ instead of $E^2=(pc)^2+(mc^{2})^2$ in general & for getting relativistic version of quantum mechanics in particular?

Comment: Do you mean $E^2=(pc)^2+(mc^2)^2$? How did you get $e=pc^2/v$? Please show a derivation/reference as this makes it easier to answer the question.

Comment: What quantum mechanical operator would you use for $v$ in the position representation?

Comment: @Philip The first equation was (and is) dimensionally consistent, and is correct. The second wasn’t, but is now. See my comment on the answer about how to derive the first.

Comment: It is correct dimensionally.

Comment: @G.Smith Ah right, I wasn't paying enough attention, removing my comment.

Comment: What operator can be used for $v$ ? Can anyone suggest an operator for $v$ please?

Answer (score 2):

The formula $E^{2}=p^{2}c^{2}+m^{2}c^{4}$ (which I have corrected in the question) depends only on a single unknown quantity, the magnitude of the momentum $p=|\vec{p}|$.  The mass is also involved, but the mass of a body (unlike its momentum) does not change unless the nature of the body itself changes.  A formula like $E=pc^{2}/v$ depends on both $p$ and $v=|\vec{v}|$, but $p$ and $v$ are not independent quantities; the energy is actually determined by $p$ or $v$ alone.  A propagating state in a quantum-mechanical scattering problem is determined just by its momentum, so $E=pc^{2}/v$ does not contain enough information to determine the energy unless it is supplemented with the (mass-dependent) relationship between $v$ and $p$.  And since $v=\partial E/\partial p$, you need the expression ($E^{2}=p^{2}c^{2}+m^{2}c^{4}$) for $E$ as a function of $p$ alone to get $v$.

Comment: The OP’s equation is correct. It follows from $E=\gamma mc^2$ and $p=\gamma mv$. It appears more often in the forms $p=Ev/c^2$ and $v=pc^2/E$. You should not have “corrected” it to $E=pv$.

Comment: @G.Smith Yeah, you're right.  My bad.

Comment: Thanx buzz, so basically you mean since p & v are dependent “variable” quantities, it’s futile to use both in an equation describing a relation between two quantities i.e. E (sorry for using e in original query) & p, where as m is a constant quantity, aptly relating the two. Is that what you mean??

Answer (score 1):

It is because your equation only makes sense in 1D. The equation for velocity In terms of momentum and energy is $$\mathbf{v}=\frac{c^2}{E} \mathbf{p}.$$ You cannot go ahead and solve for $E$ in this equation because you cannot divide by a vector. Also, the equation blows up when $v=0$.